# Stop an already scheduled nstimer

Tags: ios, nstimer

I am starting a timer to trigger an event based on a false condition.However if the condition becomes true within the scheduled time, i need to stop the event from triggering.

```
if(!condition)
{
  myTimer =[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:200 target:self selector:@selector(trigger:) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
}
else
{
 if([myTimer isvalid])
   [myTimer invalidate]
   myTimer= nil;
}
```

**If condition becomes true within 200 sec don't trigger the @selector.**

Invalidating the timer doesn't stop the method from triggering. I can do this by having a BOOL flag, but can i do it using NSTimer's methods.

Comment: [myTimer invalidate] [myTimer Nil]

Comment: Try setting the timer to nil after invalidating it `myTimer = nil;`

Comment: I tried that too no use. check updated code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must be creating multiple instance of `myTimer`. Check whether `myTimer` already initailized or not ?

```
if(!condition)
{
  if(myTimer == nil)
     myTimer =[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:200 target:self selector:@selector(trigger:) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
}
else
{
 if([myTimer isvalid])
   { 
     [myTimer invalidate]
      myTimer = nil;
    }
}
```

Comment: multiple instance was the problem thankyou @bhumeshwer